# How to unlink an app from Admob

Tags: android, upload, admob, unlink, google-play

Im starting to develop android applications, and I recently uploaded an app to the Play Store. In my admob account, i accidentally created 2 apps with the same name. Turns out that i linked the wrong app to my real app. Although, i was pretty sure that i linked the right one.

http://puu.sh/74RpK.png

In the picture you can see that the second app is the one that is uploaded, and the first one was a test, and its the one wich is not linked. My question is if there's a way of unlinking the app from admob, so i can link it correctly?
Thanks for reading :D

Answer (score 3):

'Make sure you link the correct app as you will not be able to modify it later.' :/
https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3034835?hl

Comment: Updated link to the answer:

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3034835?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can move them from one place to another. In the ad units tab check the ones you want to move then click the upper move button

Answer (score -1):

You can Link and Unlink from Admob. Goto this [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165?hl=en) and follow the steps. 
Or directly goto this [link](https://apps.admob.com/) then click `Analyze`. Then process as like below image. [image]